# bootstrap cascading dropdownlist knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have 2 dropdownlists. Area and subarea. When I choose an area I want to populate the subarea dropdownlist. I have it all working without knockout but I can't figure out how to use knockout data binding instead of js do handle the change event.

script: ???

html:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.DropDownList("AreaID", AreaList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AreaID)
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaNodeID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.DropDownList("AreaNodeID", new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control" } )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AreaNodeID)
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at this example http://www.programmerguide.net/2013/11/cascading-dropdown-using-knockoutjs-and.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.DropDownList("AreaID", AreaList, new { @class = "form-control" }, 
                    new { onchange = "FetchStates();" })



function FetchStates() {    
    var countryCode = $("#AreaID").val();
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetStates/" + countryCode, null, function (data) {
        objVM.states(data);
    });
```